# Apache on CentOS 7: configuration

Tags: apache, centos7

I have installed apache and tetsing page (http://localhost) works.
But every time I visti this page in /var/log/httpd/error_log appeared this error:

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory
>   index forbidden by Options directive

I tried to display subpage of index.html (http://localhost) and it doesn't work and I am wondering if it is connect with that error.

Answer (score 0):

I have two things on mind...
Did you set the correct permission? (http://www.petefreitag.com/item/793.cfm)

Did you specify DirectoryIndex in http.conf?

Here are two related pages with a similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/644639/wordpress-and-apache-2-4-installation-troubles-cannot-serve-directory
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/directory-index-forbidden-by-rule-var-www-html-40030/